# Use once on models in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a function in category_controller.rb:

```
def index
 @categories = Category.search(params[:search]).order name: :asc
 if @categories
 else
  @categories = Category.all.order name: :asc
 end
end
```

This code works. But this queries to model twice. How can i only query once to model but keep role of my code?

Comment: well, there are 2 different queries and so will query the db twice..what's the issue there?

Comment: by the way, your `if..else..` is always `truthy`. even if `search` returns empty `activerecord array`, `if @categories` is always true, you need to check `.present?` on it

Comment: jusst only don't query twice in model is ok

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to do it like this

```
def index
 @categories = params[:search] ? Category.search(params[:search]).order(name: :asc) : Category.all.order(name: :asc)
end
```

Comment: nay, it's possible that even if `params[:search]` is present, the results are empty and i m pretty sure it's not what OP wants

Comment: if do that system will load twice because use 2 times param[:search] from form_tag